# Authorized access to merchant's real time transactions using the REST Api

Tags: paypal, oauth, paypal-webhooks

My use case: as a third party platform I want to have access to my merchant's transactions, as soon as possible.

I could probably ask my merchants to go to their admin panel and set their IPN URL to my service but I'd prefer the authorization experience to be more user friendly. So instead, I've been trying to get authorized to set up webhooks for the merchants. From what I checked it is possible to ask third parties for authorization with the `https://uri.paypal.com/services/applications/webhooks` scope and get a refresh and access tokens to the REST Api. But when I try to use those credentials to create new hooks, the hooks were created for my application and not for the merchant's. I tried using `PayPal-Auth-Assertion` header instead of the merchant's access token but again, even though the requests were successful, the hooks were being created for my app only. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do? Is it possible to get authorized to create webhooks for some third party account?

If it's not possible, do you have some suggestions about different methods I could use? I've looked briefly into polling the `/v1/reporting/transactions` API but it can have couple of hours of delay.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of third party, get a client id and secret for the merchant's account from the 'live' tab of [developer.paypal.com](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications) (use that URL for sign-in).

Comment: I don't think it is acceptable for our business to ask our partners to give us their secret. Merchants are separate businesses and we should not have full access to their accounts.

Comment: Who said anything about full access to accounts? API credentials are API credentials.

Comment: Yeah, and with those API credentials you're able to access their funds and make payouts.

Comment: Only if the account has Payouts enabled, which is not standard. The permission can be controlled in the app settings for precisely this reason -- see link above.